The Episode In Which Fry Enters His Mother's Dream in Futurama
I found these images on an online forum but no one seemed to be mentioning what episode it was. 
In this episode (from what I read in the forum) Fry enters his Mom's dream, probably Nibbler helps him do this. 
Here's a screenshot


It's Game of Tones (Season 7, Episode 23).

The Planet Express crew enter Fry's dreams and find themselves back in the year 1999 in search of a mysterious alien song.

In the end:

Fry has a dream about his mother, and once more expresses his desire to speak with her. When a television sportscaster announces the results of the 2000 Rose Bowl, Fry is confused; since that game took place after he was frozen, it should be impossible for him to know the results. Nibbler appears, and reveals that this is not actually Fry's dream; it is one of his mother's, and is the gift that Nibbler spoke of. Fry asks if it is really her, and she replies that it is, telling him that she has dreamed of him often since his disappearance. When she asks him what he would like to talk about, he wordlessly embraces her with tears in his eyes. Back in the 21st century, Fry's mother dreams of her son with a smile on her face.

Here's the ending:




Perfect! This is the episode :) Thanks for the quick answer, I recently started watching Futurama and really liking it.
